# how do I transform this dataframe and apply a filter to the cells?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda, transpose

Third case in two days!

I have the following dataframe snippet (where the columns were originally multi-indexed, but after saving the df to CSV and reading it back in I lost the indexing and the second level is actually a row):

**edited:**

```
model     model_a       model_a         model_b         model_b
NaN       b             pvalue          b               pvalue
predictor NaN           NaN             NaN             NaN 
aches     0.6991801946  0.33372434223   0.3523114106    0.0359096002
cough     0.7164202952  0.00796337569   0.7405228672    0.0473180859
```

My use case is to now transpose the predictors `ache` and `cough` as columns and the top level of the indexed columns as rows, such that if the `pvalue` is <= 0.05, the cell should be null, otherwise the value of `b` should be in that cell. I assume the evaluation of the `pvalue` will be in a lambda function, but I may be wrong!

The desired dataframe thus would be:

```
model      aches           cough            
model_a    NaN          0.7164202952
model_b    0.3523114106 0.7405228672
```

To be honest, I have absolutely no idea how to do this, let alone how to begin. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `pd.IndexSlice` with `where`

```
out = df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'b']].where(df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'pvalue']].values<0.05).T.reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
       aches     cough
ma       NaN  0.716420
mb  0.352311  0.740523
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`...possible issue with empty cells in second and third rows? See edit above.

Comment: Is it possible that since the shape of my dataframe is
`Out[216]: (26, 27)` that would be the issue (my snippet was 5x5)?

Comment: It look like when I saved this to CSV and read it in again I lost the mullti-index. I am updating mu question appropriately based on this.

Comment: Did this, and now just fighting with a str that should be a float: `test = df.T.set_index(0, append=1).T`

Comment: it works, except the predictor names are not being transposed accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting integer column names: `1` `2`, etc.

Comment: Figured it out. It was a royal PITA!